# Typescript: Are there any conventions to document code with comments?

Tags: c#, typescript, documentation, comments, conventions

I am used to document code in our C# projects in a specific way to enhance team productivity, benefit from Intellisense in Visual Studio etc.

Code looks similar to this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads a user with a specific id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The id of the user to search for.</param>
/// <returns>A user with the given id.</returns>
public User GetUserById(string id) {
    ...
}
```

Are there any similar conventions for Typescript for commenting and documentation? Or even tools that use these conventions to generate documentation pages in html from code comments (like JavaDoc)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there are.

Most common used comment conventions (to no surprise) comes from javascript in form of [jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html). For example VSCode support them [out of the box](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_jsdoc-support).
Also there are some tools specifically developed for typescript doc generation like [typedoc](http://typedoc.org/)

Comment: Thank you, I just realized, that Visual Studio supports comments in this format, too. Just had to type `/**` in the line before a method and it inserted a comment with autogenerated @param elements.

Comment: JSDoc shouldn't be preferred as it provides type annotation which is irrelevant for Typescript since its a strongly typed language.

Comment: is there an updated url?  usejsdoc goes to a landing page for domain registration.

Answer (score 10):

[TSDoc](https://github.com/microsoft/tsdoc) is the latest proposed convention for commenting and documentation of Typescript source file. Its notation looks as follows -

```
/**
 * Returns the average of two numbers.
 *
 * @remarks
 * This method is part of the {@link core-library#Statistics | Statistics subsystem}.
 *
 * @param x - The first input number
 * @param y - The second input number
 * @returns The arithmetic mean of `x` and `y`
 */
function getAverage(x: number, y: number): number {
  return (x + y) / 2.0;
}
```

[TypeDoc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc) tool can parse comments in this convention & generates documentation pages in HTML.

Comment: Your answer's totally correct, it's probably worth noting that as of the time of writing this, TypeDoc's repo has been updated 2 weeks ago while TSDoc's has been updated 7 months ago.